# MQTT in Flutter won't connect

Tags: flutter, mqtt

So as the title says, I can't manage to create a flutter project that works with MQTT. I'm a beginner in flutter, so I tried to find some example of what I needed in github. I found a few and manage to build (mostly copy) this code, that just a simple page with 2 buttons, to connect to MQTT, and to subscribe to a topic.

```
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_browser_client.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

MqttBrowserClient client =
MqttBrowserClient('ws://127.0.0.1', 'flutter01');

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  MyAppState createState()=> MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return
      MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home:new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("My app"),),
          body: Center(
          child:new Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: connect, child: const Text("Connect")),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: subscribe, child: const Text("Subscribe"))
            ],
          ),
          ),
        )

      );
  }

  Future<MqttBrowserClient> connect() async {

    client.logging(on: true);
    client.port = 8080;
    client.onConnected = onConnected;
    client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    client.onUnsubscribed = onUnsubscribed;
    client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
    client.onSubscribeFail = onSubscribeFail;
    client.pongCallback = pong;
    client.setProtocolV311();
    final connMessage = MqttConnectMessage()
        .withWillTopic('willtopic')
        .withWillMessage('Will message')
        .startClean()
        .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    client.connectionMessage = connMessage;
    client.setProtocolV311();
    try {
      await client.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Exception: $e');
      client.disconnect();
    }

    client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
      final MqttPublishMessage message = c[0].payload;
      final payload =
      MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(message.payload.message);

      print('Received message:$payload from topic: ${c[0].topic}>');
    });
    client = client;
    return client;
  }

  //Subscribe
  void subscribe(){
    client.subscribe("topic/test", MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
  }
// connection succeeded
  void onConnected() {
    print('Connected');
  }

// unconnected
  void onDisconnected() {
    print('Disconnected');
  }

// subscribe to topic succeeded
  void onSubscribed(String topic) {
    print('Subscribed topic: $topic');
  }

// subscribe to topic failed
  void onSubscribeFail(String topic) {
    print('Failed to subscribe $topic');
  }

// unsubscribe succeeded
  void onUnsubscribed(String topic) {
    print('Unsubscribed topic: $topic');
  }

// PING response received
  void pong() {
    print('Ping response client callback invoked');
  }

}
```

It uses MQTT_browser_client, that is meant to work on a web browser, as I understand it. The goal is that my app works on mobile as well, and I know that I need to use MQTT_server_client for that, but for now I just want something that works on either.

It seems that I have to use websockets when working with this library, because whenever I don't add ws:// at the beginning of the address, I get a errors saying I need to. So I opened my local Mosquitto server to ws by adding `listener 8080` and `protocol websockets` in the conf file.

Anyway, whenever I run this code, I get this :

```
1-2022-01-25 09:36:52.123 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2022-01-25 09:36:57.151 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
1-2022-01-25 09:36:57.151 -- SynchronousMqttBrowserConnectionHandler::internalConnect failed
Exception: mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed onnection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?
1-2022-01-25 09:36:57.152 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::disconnect - entered
1-2022-01-25 09:36:57.153 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::_performConnectionDisconnect entered
Disconnected
```

I tried every several combination of ip/port (I also have a regular 1883 open), I tried connecting to public brokers (broker.emx.io, test.mosquitto.org), but nothing works.
I think the problem might be coming from websockets, since it not something I'm familiar with and I never used them before, and I would like to not have to use them, but if I want my code to run on browser I have to. And with this library it seems that I don't have a choice even for mobiles, cause I can't make the thing work of my phone either.

Can anyone clue me in on what I'm doing wrong please ?

Answer (score -1):

IF your broker is listening on port `8080` then you need to include that in the websocket URI as without a port number it will default to port `80`

```
ws://127.0.0.1:8080
```

not

```
ws://127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I'm adding the port when adding the parameters of the client : `client.port = 8080;`

Comment: OK, but what happens if you set it in the URI?

Comment: Same error, it still won't connect